# Can the complex function $f(z) = \sqrt[n]{r^n - z^n}$ be analytically continued to fill the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

I have the complex function $f(z) = \sqrt[n]{r^n - z^n}$, where $z$ is a complex variable, $r$ is a positive real number, and $n$ is any non-zero real number. For any value of $n$ besides 1, this function does not fill the entire complex plane, instead occupying only a portion of it. I know that analytic continuation can be used to extend analytic functions to the full complex plane, but I can't figure out how to

1. Determine if $f(z) = \sqrt[n]{r^n - z^n}$ is analytic, and, if it is,
2. Carry out the analytic continuation of $f(z)$.

The highest level of math class I have taken is Calc 1, so while I know the basics of complex numbers, I don't have any knowledge of Complex Analysis besides what Google, Wikipedia, and WolframAlpha can tell me.

Can someone explain how to go about figuring this out?

**UPDATE:** I figured out that the function $f(z) = \sqrt[n]{r^n - z^n}$ can be represented by the Taylor Series

$$
f(z) = r × \sum_{k = 0}^∞ \left({\left(\frac{z}{r}\right)^{k × n} × \frac{Γ\left(k - \frac{1} {n}\right)} {Γ(k + 1) × Γ\left(\frac{-1} {n}\right)}}\right)
$$

which I *think* means that it is indeed analytic. However, I'm still confused as to how to carry out analytic continuation on the function.

Comment: First get rid of $r:$ $f(z)=rg(z/r)$ for $g(u):=\sqrt[n]{1-u^n}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval How does that help?

Comment: The problem is equivalent but just simpler to write and read, hence hopefully also to solve ;-)

Comment: $r^n-z^n$ has a simple zero at $r$ so its $n$-th root has a branch point at $r$.

Comment: @reuns What does that mean?